# C++ console applications writen with XCode 6.3 crash

Tags: c++, xcode, libc++

Any code could crash... while the same code is OK with VC++.

This is just one of them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    mutex lock;

    auto loop = [&lock](string name) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            lock.lock();

            cout << name << ' ' << i << endl;

            lock.unlock();

            this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
        }
    };

    auto a = thread(loop, "A");
    auto b = thread(loop, "B");

    a.join();
    b.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The application crashes when starting the thread with the constructor of `tuple` accessing some null pointer.

And if I put the source code of libc++ into my project instead of linking to the dylib, the problem is gone...

I rarely wrote C++ console applications on Mac OS X before. I wonder if this is my problem or apple's.

---

The call stack at the point of crash:

With that `char const*&&` (not the `char const *`)referencing nothing.

```
#0  0x0000000100000c7b in std::__1::__tuple_leaf<1ul, char const*, false>::__tuple_leaf<char const*, void>(char const*&&) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/tuple:222
#1  0x0000000100000c77 in std::__1::__tuple_impl<std::__1::__tuple_indices<0ul, 1ul>, main::$_0, char const*>::__tuple_impl<0ul, 1ul, main::$_0, char const*, main::$_0, char const*>(std::__1::__tuple_indices<0ul, 1ul>, std::__1::__tuple_types<main::$_0, char const*>, std::__1::__tuple_indices<>, std::__1::__tuple_types<>, main::$_0&&, char const*&&) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/tuple:416
#2  0x0000000100000c41 in std::__1::__tuple_impl<std::__1::__tuple_indices<0ul, 1ul>, main::$_0, char const*>::__tuple_impl<0ul, 1ul, main::$_0, char const*, main::$_0, char const*>(std::__1::__tuple_indices<0ul, 1ul>, std::__1::__tuple_types<main::$_0, char const*>, std::__1::__tuple_indices<>, std::__1::__tuple_types<>, main::$_0&&, char const*&&) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/tuple:416
#3  0x0000000100000c2a in std::__1::tuple<main::$_0, char const*>::tuple<main::$_0, char const*, false>(main::$_0&&, char const*&&) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/tuple:569
#4  0x0000000100000bf5 in std::__1::tuple<main::$_0, char const*>::tuple<main::$_0, char const*, false>(main::$_0&&, char const*&&) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/tuple:569
#5  0x0000000100000bd2 in std::__1::thread::thread<main::$_0&, char const (&) [2], void>(main::$_0&&&, char const (&&&) [2]) at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:352
#6  0x0000000100000ab5 in std::__1::thread::thread<main::$_0&, char const (&) [2], void>(main::$_0&&&, char const (&&&) [2]) at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:359
#7  0x0000000100000998 in main at /Users/blue/Documents/_/Test1/Test1/main.cpp:27
#8  0x00007fff863545c9 in start ()
```

The funny thing is that the code works in release mode. While some other code work in debug mode but not release mode.

Comment: Works fine for me (Xcode 6.3). You're mentioning `tuple`'s constructor in your question but I don't see it in the code... could you provide the stack trace?

Comment: @Hiura I've post the stack. And I found mine is 6.3, too...

Comment: Works great for me:  `$ clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ junk.cpp -g && ./a.out`  `$ clang++ -v` gives:  Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)

Comment: @BlueWanderer The code does not even compile. "sleep_for(10ms)" is not valid.

Comment: @BlueWanderer What is the "other code" you refer too?